# The request resourse is not available

Tags: jsf, tomcat, jsf-2, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I am trying to write my first JSF application and have a problem with deploying it on servers Apache Tomcat 8.0 / GlassFish 4.

For example, I use an application described in Horstmann's Core Java Server Faces([it is from Source code from here named ch01](http://corejsf.com)). According to the book, I should do (for Win 7 x64):

- From path **ch01/login/src/java** compline the project using this line command:

If you using Tomcat : 
**javac -d ..\..\web\WEB-INF\classes -classpath .;my_path_to_lib\lib\jsf-api.jar com\corejsf\UserBean.java**

If you using Glassfish: **javac -d .\..\web\WEB-INF\classes -classpath .;path_to_glassfish\glassfish\modules* com\corejsf\UserBean.java**

- Then I make a war file, using: **cd ..\.. jar cvf login.war**
- And of course I put these files into webapp (Tomcat) or domain\domain1\autodeploing (GlassFish)

But after these steps I im trying to run application and it is not working in both of the servers. All what I see the usual **The requested resource is not available.**

I have no idea what should I do. Could someone help me, please?

For more information:

1. I don't try to start application in the same time on both servers and the use different ports :)
2. In addition to jsf-api.jar I include javax.faces-api-2.0.jar cause without it compiler catch a error.
3. To run application from browser I type localhost:8080/login (or localhost:8081/login)
4. I consider these source code are right including files:

   - index.xhtml
   - welcome.xhtml
   - web.xml
   - UserBean.java

Directory structure:

```
login\
     src\
     |  java\
     |      com\
     |         corejsf\
     |                UserBean.java
     web\
        WEB-INF\
        |      classes\
        |      |      com\ 
        |      |         corejsf\
        |      |                UserBean.class
        |      lib\
        |      |  javax.faces-api.2.0.jar
        |      |  jsf-api.jar
        |      |
        |      web.xml
        |
        index.xhtml
        welcome.xhtml
```

And about maven: yes, I want to run this application without using maven to understand how it works directly. Thanks

Comment: Can you post the directory and file structure within your war file? And additionally - is there a special reason why you don't use a build tool like maven?

Comment: I added my application structure to main topic.(sorry, I am newbie in this site)

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution! The problem was in the directory structure. I have just change it like this:

```
login\
     src\
     |  java\
     |      com\
     |         corejsf\
     |                UserBean.java
     WEB-INF\
     |      classes\
     |      |      com\ 
     |      |         corejsf\
     |      |                UserBean.class
     |      lib\
     |      |  javax.faces-api.2.0.jar
     |      |  jsf-api.jar
     |      |
     |      web.xml
     |
     index.xhtml
     welcome.xhtml
```

In other words I remove **web** directory and put WEB-INF,index.xhtml,welcome.xhtml into application folder. But I still confused why the book's structure is different... And I can run it only in GlassFish 4

Comment: I think there should be used some special libraries for running it on Tomcat cause it catch an error: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet. So, I can conclude that there is multiple conflict with JAR's